# Simplifying logarithms and changing base

Tags: logarithms

I have been asked to find the value of

$8^{\log_{2} 5}$

I understand that I could proceed to turn this into

$\log_{8} x = \log_{2} 5$

Where do I go from there? I assumed changing both to the same base, but I'm not sure how to do so or what to do after having the same base for both sides.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $8=2^3$ and $2^{log_2 5}=5$, we have 
$$8^{log_2 5}=(2^3)^{log_2 5}=(2^{log_2 5})^3=5^3=125$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $8 = 2^3$ and whenever $x = y > 0$ you can deduce $\log_2(x) = \log_2(y)$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\log_b a = \dfrac{\log_c a}{\log_c b}$ so in this case $$\log_2 5 = \frac{\log_8 5}{\log_8 2} = \frac{\log_8 5}{\log_8 8^{1/3}} = 3\log_8 5 = \log_8 5^3$$

So that $$8^{\displaystyle \log_2 5} = 8^{\displaystyle \log_8 5^3} = 5^3 = 125$$

Note that $a^{\displaystyle \log_a x} = x$ by virtue of the composition of $a^x$ with its inverse $\log_a x$, giving $\mathrm{id}$.

Comment: Your identity in your very first line is false for lots of different $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\log_25=y\implies2^y=5$

Now $8^{\log_25}=(2^3)^y=(2^y)^3=5^3$

**See** [Laws of Logarithms](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Laws_of_Logarithms)  and [Exponent Combination Laws](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_Combination_Laws)

Comment: The ProofWiki article you cite is plainly wrong. Please don't give students incorrect references.

Comment: @user21820, Please pinpoint the mistakes.

Comment: I'm surprised you can't see the mistakes yourself. Try $a=1$.

Comment: @user21820, True, $a$ should be $>0,\ne1$

Comment: And $b \ne 1$... If you've a ProofWiki account you should fix it before citing it again. I don't have one.

Answer (score 2):

$\log_8x=\log_25 \implies \frac{1}{3} \log_2 x = \log_2 5 \implies \log_2 x = 3\log_2 5 \implies \log_2 x = \log_2 125$

Since $\log_k x$ is a bijective function over $\mathbb R^+$, $k \in (0,1)\cup(1,+\infty)$

$x = 125$

Comment: Specify what is $k$.

Comment: @user21820 sure.

Comment: Not enough. Try $k=1$.

Comment: By the way use `\log` for the proper formatted "$\log$", and `\frac{1}{3}` for "$\frac{1}{3}$".

Comment: @user21820 Okay